# error C4996: 'std::_Equal1': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I downloaded [libtins](https://libtins.github.io/) and set up a new project to mess around with it.

When I try to compile the example code I'm getting the following error:

```
main.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3017): error C4996: 'std::_Equal1': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3002) : see declaration of 'std::_Equal1'
c:\users\admin\documents\libtins-latest-win32\libtins-latest-win32\include\ipv6_address.h(140) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::equal<Tins::IPv6Address::const_iterator,Tins::IPv6Address::const_iterator>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2)' being compiled
with
[
_InIt1=Tins::IPv6Address::const_iterator,
_InIt2=Tins::IPv6Address::const_iterator
]
```

I added the definition to disable this warning but it doesn't work. It still gives me this error when I try to compile

This is the code referenced in the error https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/blob/master/include/ipv6_address.h#L140

Can someone please help me, I don't know what to do?

Comment: What did you define and how did you define it?

Comment: I put the `D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in the preprocessor definitions in visual studio

Comment: You should be defining `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, not `D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

Comment: Okay thanks the error is gone I';m stupid sorry